# Can kibana connect with data sources other than elastic search?

Tags: hive, kibana

Can Kibana connect with data sources other than elastic search and build visualizations on the data in other data sources ?
More specifically I am looking to connect Kibana with Hive.

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot connect Kibana directly but you can connect Elasticsearch to hadoop. 
using es-hadoop see https://www.elastic.co/products/hadoop

Similarly you can connect other datasources to elasticsearch like Logstash, es-hadoop or 3rd party technologies like Apache Flume, Fluentd, and many others.
see - https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana