# Can I connect Kibana with Amazon Redshift?

Tags: kibana, amazon-redshift

I am having a difficulty connecting Kibana with Amazon Redshift.

- Is there a way to connect Kibana without Elasticsearch?
- Is there a way to directly connect Kibana with Amazon Redshift for visualisation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can kibana connect with data sources other than elastic search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706544/can-kibana-connect-with-data-sources-other-than-elastic-search)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You have to ingest the data in elastic from beat/ logstash and then use kibana for the visualization.

Answer (score 1):

No. Kibana only works with Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks John.I am having mydata in redshift . i want to use kibana for viz.could you guide me how to proceed . (ubuntu interface)

Comment: Any possibility to transfer data from redshift to elasticsearch?

Comment: Probably. Please ask it as a new Question.